# Why Nginx logs the error: upstream sent invalid status "0 0" while reading response header from upstream?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

This is the error logged by Nginx:

> upstream sent invalid status "0 0" while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: 192.168.14.163, server: , request: "POST
>   /media/course-discuss-comment/comment HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.14.46"

What may be the cause of the **status "0 0"**? Please give me some hints.

The environment: Ubuntu 14.04.1, Nginx 1.9.3, PHP 5.5.9